# Suggestions for a reading

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

I had read basic number theory and also I had solved many problems in number theory.
To widen my knowledge I want to explore more number theory. I am interested in conjectures like bertrand conjecture, goldbach conjecture. I also like to study the infinitude of primes in an arithmetic progressions.
I want some guidance in this. Which books should I read to know more about such amazing properties. 
Thanks

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but Bertrand's conjecture was proved by Chebyshev mid-19th century. Anyway, you could try Davenport's book, Multiplicative Number Theory.

Comment: My favorite book on this subject is ***An illustrated theory of numbers*** by Martin Weissman.

Comment: The common name is "Bertrand's postulate" , which , as mentioned , has been proven. Goldbach's conjecture is apparently out of reach but almost every (if not every) mathematician is convinced that it is true. Dirichlet's theorem (every sequence $an+b$ with coprime positive integers $a,b$ and $n$ running over the positive integers contains infinite many primes) is very difficult to prove. First study Dirichlet characters as a start. Which book you should read ? You should decide this for yourself after having looked at several books. This is a very subjective question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should read the two following books:

1. *Topics in the theory of numbers* by Erdos and Suranyi (You will enjoy most of the book)
2. *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* by Tom Apostol (You will learn lots of stuff).